# Conditions with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Given the following data:

```
diccionario_datos_clientes = [
    {"Name": "Marcos", "Age": 23, "Ranking": 14, "Contact":{ "Work": 99000001, "Personal": 7222003}},
    {"Name": "Hugo", "Age": 26, "Ranking": 83, "Contact": { "Work": 99000002, "Personal": 97220042}},
    {"Name": "Manuel", "Age": 13, "Ranking": 2, "Contact": { "Work": 99000003, "Personal": 47220003}},
    {"Name": "Maria", "Age": 66, "Ranking": 7, "Contact": { "Work": 99000004, "Personal": 47220004}},
    {"Name": "Itziar", "Age": 20, "Ranking": 23, "Contact": { "Work": 99000005, "Personal": 47220005}}
]
```

I have to see if the personal contact is valid. The conditions are the following:

- The number has to have 8 digits min
- The first number has to be 4
- The numbers in the positions 4,5,6 have to be 0.

If the number is not valid I should append the name and work contact to a list.

I was able to do the first 2 conditions but i´m having trouble with the third one.

```
    dic_llamar=[]
    for dic in diccionario_datos_clientes:
        if len(str(dic['Contact']['Personal']))<8:
            dic_llamar.append((dic['Name'],dic['Contact']['Work']))
        elif int(str(dic['Contact']['Personal'])[0])!=4:
            dic_llamar.append((dic['Name'],dic['Contact']['Work']))
```

Ask right away if something is not clear!

Comment: The third one would be: `str(dic['Contact']['Personal'])[4:7] == '000'` and also, for a contact to be valid, should it fulfill ALL conditions at the same time?

Comment: @CeliusStingher let me try that and I´ll get back to u! And yes for it to be valid it should fullfil the 3 conditions at the same time.

Comment: @CeliusStingher It worked! So thank u!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to check my answer and accept it if it helps you solve the issue! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is better to extract this into its own function

```
def isValid(number):
    """take a number and said if is a valid contact number"""
    s = str(number)
    return len(s)>=8 and s[0]=="4" and s[4:7]=="000"
```

(I don't understand why the other repeat the same so many times)

By putting it into its own function is more easy to check if it work (because it can be tested individually) and can be more easily use in other parts of your project if needed.

And use it like

```
for dic in diccionario_datos_clientes:
    if isValid(dic['Contact']['Personal']):
        #do something
    else: 
        #do something else
```

and is cleaner and more beautiful

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would help you solve the issue, I am stating all three conditions needed to be met in the `if`:

```
for dic in diccionario_datos_clientes:
  s = str(dic['Contact']['Persona'])
  if (len(s) >=8) & (s[0]=='4') & (s[4:7] == '000'):
    print("Valid contact!")
  else:
    print("Not valid contact!")
    dic_llamar.append((dic['Name'],dic['Contact']['Work']))
```

So if all conditions are met, you will get valid contact, otherwise not valid contact. Of course you can modify this to fit your best needs.

Comment: That´s perfect! Thanks for the help!

Comment: any reason to repeat the same so many times?

Comment: Would you rather define a variable and evaluate it?

Comment: @CeliusStingher of course, why would I want to do the same 3 times?

Comment: What is it that you are doing the "same" 3 times?

Comment: in your code that is `str(dic['Contact']['Personal'])`

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it this time :)

Comment: well, if we get picky you're using `&` which is a bit operator, you should use `and` which is the logical operator and is also shortcircuit

Answer (score 1):

The last condiction is

```
 if str(dic['Contact']['Personal'])[4:7] == '000':
```

On a side note, it'll be better if you used only one if:

```
condiction1 = len(str(dic['Contact']['Personal'])) == 8
condiction2 = str(dic['Contact']['Personal'])[0] == '4'
condiction3 = str(dic['Contact']['Personal'])[4:7] == '000'
if not (condiction1 or condiction2 or condiction3):
     append(...)
```